# Rewriting certain terms in Lean4

Tags: lean4

I want to prove the following theorem using a single axiom (https://mathworld.wolfram.com/WolframAxiom.html):

```
variable {A : Type}

axiom dot : A -> A -> A
infix : 50 " * " => dot

axiom wolfram_axiom (a b c : A) : (((a * b) * c) * (a * ((a * c) * a))) = c

theorem double_negation (a : A) : ((a * a) * (a * a)) = a := sorry
```

I already have a long proof from Automatic Theorem Prover in terms of many-many rewrites at certain term positions. I just want to see how it would look like in Lean. For example as my first rewrite I want to apply this term:

```
let term1 := wolfram_axiom a ((a * a) * a) a -- ((a * ((a * a) * a)) * a) * (a * ((a * a) * a))) = a
```

at a certain `a`, the 4th one for example, so that the new goal becomes this:

```
(a * a) * (a  * (((a * (a  * ((a * a) * a))) * a) * (a * ((a * a) * a)))) = a
```

How can I do it?

(Also is it possible to use `.` instead of `*` here? Lean thinks it's a function composition)

Comment: One option is to write a [`calc` proof](https://lean-lang.org/theorem_proving_in_lean4/quantifiers_and_equality.html#calculational-proofs).  Then you can explicitly state each step of the equality and then fill in a proof (maybe using `simp` with the appropriate instance of your axiom for each step).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following:

```
variable {A : Type}

axiom dot : A -> A -> A
infix : 50 " * " => dot

axiom wolfram_axiom (a b c : A) : (((a * b) * c) * (a * ((a * c) * a))) = c

example (a : A) (b : A): ((a * a) * (a * a)) = a := by
  have term1 := wolfram_axiom a ((a * a) * a) a
  rw (config := {occs := .pos [4]}) [<-term1]
  -- goal: ((a * a) * (a * (((a * ((a * a) * a)) * a) * (a * ((a * a) * a))))) = a
  sorry
```

Let's look at:

```
rw (config := {occs := .pos [4]}) [<-term1]
```

- the `<-term1` means to rewrite with `term1` but in reverse, namely

  ```
  a = (((a * ((a * a) * a)) * a) * (a * ((a * a) * a)))
  ```
- the `(config := {occs := .pos [4]})` means to rewrite at the forth possibly rewrite occurrence.  It is a list so you can put more than one number in there, or use `.neg` for specifying which occurrences not to rewrite.

All this can be found in the documentation for `rewrite` which you can get hovering over the tactic.  (The `rw` tactic annoyingly tells you to look at the documentation for `rewrite`.)

Another approach is to use `calc` mode to outline long equality proofs.  Then you only need to give a separate proof of each equality step which is often easier.  For example:

```
example (a : A) (b : A): ((a * a) * (a * a)) = a :=
  calc
    ((a * a) * (a * a)) 
      = ((a * a) * (a * (((a * ((a * a) * a)) * a) * (a * ((a * a) * a))))) := by
        rw [wolfram_axiom a ((a * a) * a) a]
    _ = a := by sorry
```

Note how the `rw` tactic is now much simpler since I can rewrite the complicated term which there is only one of.

Comment: Thanks! Works like a charm. This `occs` setting was not showing up in my documentation because I had an old version, I guess one needs to update lean more frequently :).