# Apply `unfold` once, instead of many times, in lean4

Tags: lean4, beginner

I have code that is similar in spirit to this:

```
inductive
RS where
  | leaf (value : Nat)
  | node (left : RS) (right : RS)

def count (a : Nat) (br : RS) : Nat :=
  match br with
  | RS.leaf v => a * v
  | RS.node leftB rightB => ((count a leftB) + (count a rightB))


example
  (a : Nat)
  (b : RS)
  (h : b = (RS.node l r))
  : (count a b) ≤ (2 * max (count a l) (count a r)) := by
  unfold count
  sorry
```

The problem I'm running into is that, when I use `unfold`, the goal goes from this:

`count a b ≤ 2 * max (count a left) (count a right)`

to this:

```
(match b with
  | RS.leaf v => a * v
  | RS.node leftB rightB => count a leftB + count a rightB) ≤
  2 *
    max
      (match l with
      | RS.leaf v => a * v
      | RS.node leftB rightB => count a leftB + count a rightB)
      (match r with
      | RS.leaf v => a * v
      | RS.node leftB rightB => count a leftB + count a rightB)
```

but I *wanted* this much more succinct state:

```
(match b with
  | RS.leaf v => a * v
  | RS.node leftB rightB => count a leftB + count a rightB
) ≤ 2 * max (count a l) (count a r)
```

How do I only unfold the part on the left hand side, leaving the right hand side alone?

Comment: Please provide a [MWE](https://leanprover-community.github.io/mwe.html).

Comment: @JasonRute Okay done

Comment: There may be a better approach, but you could just rewrite all but one of them (as per https://proofassistants.stackexchange.com/questions/2568/rewriting-certain-terms-in-lean4) as `count'` (where `count' := count`), unfold, and then change it back after the unfold.

Comment: @JasonRute Should we write a meta post for MWE (with non-Lean specific language) and link to that instead?

Comment: @Trebor Feel free to go ahead.  I’d be happy to link to that instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I personally don't know of a setting for this, but actually for what you are trying to do, `simp [count]` works fine in place of `unfold count`.  The key is to realize you know you can only simplify your expression when you know the structure of the recursive parameter, in this case `b`:

```
example
  (a : Nat)
  (b : RS)
  (h : b = (RS.node l r))
  : (count a b) ≤ (2 * max (count a l) (count a r)) := by
  rw [h]
  simp [count]
  /-
  l r : RS
  a : Nat
  b : RS
  h : b = RS.node l r
  ⊢ count a l + count a r ≤ 2 * max (count a l) (count a r)
  -/
  sorry
```

If you didn't have `h : b = (RS.node l r)`, then you could have done `induction b` and both branches would have let you use `simp [count]` to simplify the LHS while leaving the RHS the same.  This is a common pattern for recursive definitions.  You don't have to unfold.  Just do `induction` followed by `simp`.

Comment: Thanks, that worked.